# How can I edit an answer with a semantic error?

Tags: support

[This answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6772/how-to-set-up-bike-so-that-back-pedalling-stops-the-rear-wheel/6777#6777) contains a semantic error. The word 'taught' is used to indicate the tension of a chain where the word '[taut](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/taut)' is the correct usage.

I can't edit it because my edit would be less than 6 characters and it gets an error. I have no other edits to make because otherwise it's a good answer, it's just that one word that's confusing.

I don't want to be a grammar nazi either. Should I just leave it?

Comment: As [an editor](http://www.neilfein.com), I share your pain. People *will* make typos, it's a normal thing. Typos left uncorrected, however, make the site look bad. Once you get to 2000 rep, you can make these edits on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a very minor mistake that would never confuse anybody, you can just leave it alone.

In this case, it looks like something that could cause some confusion. If you can't edit it to fix it and can't find other edits to fix things up in the question (improve formatting), then flag it.  Moderators can fix that without the same restriction.

Comment: I made the edit, FYI.

Comment: I noticed that. I went to flag it but then it was corrected. Thanks :)